# Swift 2 Protocol extension using `pow`

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm attempting to give any number the ability to raised to an arbitrary power (specifically, 2). This seems like the perfect opportunity to use protocol extensions instead of adding an extension to `Float`, `Double`, `Int` etc.

```
protocol Raisable {
    func raise(exponent : Self) -> Self
}

extension Raisable where Self : SignedNumberType {
    func raise(exponent : Double) -> Self {
        return Self(pow(Double(self), exponent))
    }
}

protocol Squarable : Raisable {
    func squared() -> Self
}

extension Squarable {
    func squared() -> Self {
        return self.raise(2)
    }
}
```

The compiler show "Cannot find initializer for type 'Double' that accepts an argument list of type '(Self)'".

Any ideas how I can change `raise:` to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of overlapping problems here that may not resolve well (and the result wouldn't be very good even if you did). Let's walk through some of them.

```
protocol Raisable {
    func raise(exponent : Self) -> Self
}
```

OK, we already have our first problem. Consider if `Self` is `Int`. What is the result of `Int(2).raise(-1)`? It should be 0.5, but that's not an integer. Do you plan to round to 1? That's definitely different than the code you'd write for `Double`.

```
extension Raisable where Self : SignedNumberType {
    func raise(exponent : Double) -> Self {
        return Self(pow(Double(self), exponent))
    }
}
```

This requires that every possible `SignedNumberType` be convertible to and from `Double`, which isn't promised, or even desirable. For instance, a complex number meets all the requirements of `SignedNumberType`, and it is reasonable to raise a complex number to a real exponent, but then `pow` isn't the right function. You'd really need to handle these cases with differentiated code. Consider especially the case of `i^2`, which is real, so just projecting `i` onto its real component (`0`) and then squaring that would lead to a very surprising result.

```
extension Squarable {
    func squared() -> Self {
        return self.raise(2)
    }
}
```

Beyond the other problems, this is very, very slow (orders of magnitude slower than `self*self` or `self<<1` where applicable). That's not the end of the world if it significantly improved readability, but it doesn't really seem to.

Generally speaking, Swift does not encourage functions that take "some number, I don't care what type." In most cases, you need to write code to handle numeric conversion and consider the cases of overflow, truncation, etc. If you want to promote everything to `Double`, you generally need to do that intentionally, not via a protocol.

But there's still something to be learned here about extensions. We can certainly create a `squared()` method easily and attach it to various types. For example:

```
protocol Multipliable {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Multipliable {
    func squared() -> Self {
        return self * self
    }
}

extension Int: Multipliable {}
extension Double: Multipliable {}

2.squared()
(2.1).squared()
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for taking the time to write such a comprehensive answer. It looks like my enthusiasm for using new tools trumped my understanding of them this time. Cheers!

Comment: No problem at all. I've written up what your `squared()` function would look like. Done that way, there's no problem with it. You just need to be a bit more explicit and make sure you're only relying in your functions on things you require in your protocols.